# Working with many to many relationship between already existing tables in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a web-application made in elixir/phoenix.
I will keep my explanation focussed around the heading. 
So I have something in the system called `roles` and there is something called `permissions`.

The `roles` have `many-to-many` relationship with `permissions` via a middle table `role_permissions`.

The schema for the three is something along the lines of:

**roles**

```
schema "roles" do
    # associations
    has_many(:users, User)
    many_to_many(:permissions, Permission, join_through: "role_permissions")

    field(:name, :string)
    field(:description, :string)

    timestamps()
  end 

@required_params ~w(name)a
@optional_params ~w(description)a
@create_params @required_params ++ @optional_params
@update_params @required_params ++ @optional_params

@doc """
Returns a changeset to create a new `role`.
"""
@spec create_changeset(t, map) :: Ecto.Changeset.t()
def create_changeset(%__MODULE__{} = role, params) do
 role
 |> cast(params, @create_params)
 |> common_changeset()
end
```

**permissions**

```
schema "permissions" do
    field(:code, :string)
    field(:description, :string)

    timestamps()
  end
```

**role_permissions**

```
 schema "permissions" do
    belongs_to(:role, Role)
    belongs_to(:permission, Permission)

    timestamps()
  end
```

`permissions` can be created separately from roles so I have CRUD functions to create them.

However, while creating `roles` they should be associated with the `permissions`. 
In order to do that I have used a create function shown below

```
def create(%{permissions: permissions} = params) when permissions != [] do
    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.run(:role, fn _ ->
      QH.create(Role, params, Repo)
    end)
    |> permissions_multi(params)
    |> persist()
  end

defp permissions_multi(multi, params) do
    Multi.run(multi, :permission, fn %{role: role} ->
      role_permissions = associate_role_permissions(role, params[:permissions])
      {count, _} = Repo.insert_all(RolePermission, role_permissions)
      {:ok, count}
    end)
  end

  defp associate_role_permissions(role, permissions) do
    Enum.map(permissions, fn permission ->
      [permission_id: permission,
      role_id: role.id,
      inserted_at: DateTime.utc_now,
      updated_at: DateTime.utc_now]
    end)
  end

  # Run the accumulated multi struct
  defp persist(multi) do
    case Repo.transaction(multi) do
      {:ok, %{role: role}} ->
        {:ok, role}

      {:error, _, _, _} = error ->
        error
    end
  end
```

The `create/1` takes `name`, `description` and `permissions` which is a list of **permission_ids**.

Role is inserted into the db first. Upon insertion, I receive `{:ok, role}` 
I use the `associate_role_permission` to pair the role_id with all the permission ids and use `Repo.insert_all` to make an insertion in the middle table.

All this works fine, I have written tests for this and it works.

The **problem arises when I am moving to UI with phoenix**.

The controller

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = RoleSchema.create_changeset(%RoleSchema{}, %{permissions: nil})
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

"new.html" is as follows:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, [as: :role], fn f -> %>
  <%= input f, :name %>
  <%= input f, :description %>
  <%= multiple_select(f, :permissions, formatted_list(:permissions))%>
  <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary submit-btn" %>
  <%= link("Cancel", to: role_path(@conn, :index), class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
```

What I am trying to do here is create a dropdown for multi-select from the 
list of permissions I am loading in the format [{:code, :id}] which works fine.

But I am constantly receiving the error

```
protocol Phoenix.HTML.Safe not implemented for #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :permissions is not loaded>.
```

I know the error is because in the changeset the data field has
permissions not loaded.

**What should be a workaround for this problem**?

Is there a way to modify a particular field in the `changeset.data` field, is this even the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly [`Ecto.Query.preload/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) each association, `Ecto` won’t do it silently. Your `RoleSchema` has an association there in `:permissions` and since it’s not preloaded in the newly created changeset, it returns the [`Ecto.Association.NotLoaded`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Association.NotLoaded.html) struct, which is temporarily substituting the real value until the association is loaded.

Since you are *creating* a `changeset` here, just explicitly update it’s data like:

```
changeset = RoleSchema.create_changeset(%RoleSchema{})
changeset = update_in(changeset.data, &Repo.preload(&1, :permissions))
...
```